# What point and shoot can be used with an external trigger (for timelapse)?

Tags: point-and-shoot, timelapse

I'm looking for a PS camera that has an external trigger.
Lowest priced I know of with a physical trigger is the G12 from Canon.
But any PS with IR is good enough for my use (time-lapse triggering).

No CHDK. I can't use it here because of Eye-Fi endless shooting problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [wired](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?lensattachment=fixed&remotewired=1) or [IR](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?lensattachment=fixed&remoteinfrared=1)? Each has a few options.

I think the [Pentax Optio I10](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/pentax/i10) is the cheapest, about $200, plus this one is actually P&S, the Canon G12 is an advanced model.

Comment: hi, i have solutions for triggering both IR and WIRED .  
i will be making my own trigger remote using a micro-controller and ir or cable
thanks for neocam site, looks great.

Comment: neocam is great but a bit missleading in detail, the G12 does have an external trigger, afaik. http://www.neocamera.com/camera/canon/g12

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I will check with Canon as the information they sent me (I'm the editor of Neocamera) does not mention a remote trigger.